# Best iPhone/iOS framework for Presentation Apps

Tags: iphone, frameworks, ios, presentation

Which framework do you suggest for building an application to manage presentation, like an interactive and multimedia brochure?
Do you think the iOS is enough?

Comment: as a historic note, it used to be Corona for a little while!

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the previously mentioned great Corona, you can have a look at the HTML-JavaScript-CSS-based [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com). It is good if your application can be considered "page based" (you can still do animations with it, I did most of the games at VersusPad.com using it).